# Pseudo-classes after getting horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I am using a css pseudo-classes. I tried `before` and `after`. There is no issue with `before` I am getting the horizontal scroll when using `after` class.

I don't want to use `overflow: hidden;`. If I use overflow then my image is displaying behind the first section.

Would you help me out with these issues?

**This is the before class which is working.**

```css
.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}


/*.test1{position: relative;}*/

.test1:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://w0.pngwave.com/png/546/532/computer-icons-sales-label-sale-icon-png-clip-art.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 350px;
  height: 308px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  left: -10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="test1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

  </section>
</div>
```

**This is the `after` class which is not working. I am getting scrollbar**

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.test1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test1:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/16-165891_sale-price-tag-png-sale-icon-png.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 350px;
  height: 308px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  right: -10%;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section class="test1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

</section>
```

I am getting the output

[image]
My expected output

[image]

Comment: I see horizontal scroll in both cases. Don't fully understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @demkovych run the snippet on full page

Comment: this is the logical result, since the default direction is left to right then only the right overflow is considered and trigger an scroll

Comment: ass position relative to your container and set right: 0 to image. You have a scroll because your image is outside the main container

Comment: @demkovych,  sorry for the late reply. I am not getting the scroll in before class. What I am doing is, I have to display the image on the left side and right side with half on screen.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Thanks for the information. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please add css

```
body {position: relative;}

.test1:after {
content: "";
background-image: url(https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/16-165891_sale-price-tag-png-sale-icon-png.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 350px;
height: 400px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/*.test1{position: relative;}*/
.test1 {position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
.test1:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://w0.pngwave.com/png/546/532/computer-icons-sales-label-sale-icon-png-clip-art.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 350px;
  height: 308px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  left: 0;
}

.test1:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/16-165891_sale-price-tag-png-sale-icon-png.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 350px;
  height: 308px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  right: -40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="test1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: you removed right value. I need to display half image on screen. Now it is displaying full.

Comment: This is my expected output https://prnt.sc/r1q9wo

Comment: you have to use overflow:hidden property